# Create a container directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I'm trying to create a directive that will layout a collection of items in columns.
In the plunker I have a extremely simplified version which only uses a single ul, but that is not important. I want the directive to be called like .

```
<my-column-layout collection="names">
    <tab name="{{ item }}"></tab>
</my-column-layout>
```

I want to use the inner html (the tab here) as a template for each item in the collection. I tried to just
have a ng-repeat in the my-column-layout template like

```
template : '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in collection" ng-transclude></li></ul>
```

which worked but it didnt have access to the containing controllers scope, so I couldn't have any click events on the tab and have it call an function in the controller.
So i think I am heading the right direction with using transclude but not sure. Also when I try to add some other name to the collection of names, then this doesnt show up in the collection in my directive. My scope.$watch('collection' ...) is never called.

http://plnkr.co/edit/4vyZDAhBcbULEd3uIznh?p=preview

Hope someone can help

Comment: I changed your code and fixed the problems. http://plnkr.co/edit/TW7YS2NLatuhzj6o0toX?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something that I think is similar.  Let me know if I've somehow missed the point.  I have a directive that does a transcluded ng-repeat based on remote data.  Here's how it works.

**Update**

It's the template in the page markup that's the issue.  However, if you want the ng-repeat template to exist on the same page markup, you can do this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="navbar.html">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{active: item.selected}">
        <a href="/{{item.link}}">{{item.title}}</a>
    </li>
</script>
```

Not exactly the same thing, but it get's you the same effect - template on the same page as the directive - just not nested with it.

**Update End**

I have the same array in the parent and the child scopes: i.e. `$scope.items`.  Because it's a reference type, through prototypical inheritance, both scopes reference the same object. In the location that doesn't update the property, I initialize it like this `$scope.items = $scope.items || [];` -- i.e. if the property hasn't been initialized, initialize it, otherwise keep it.

```
directive('navbar', ['$location', '$http',  function ($location, $http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: { heading: '@'},
        controller: 'NavbarCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'navbar.html',
        replace: true,
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, navbarCtrl) {

            $scope.items = [];
            $scope.heading = $scope.heading || $attrs.heading;

            $http.get(itemsUrl).success(function(data) {
                $scope.items = ... async get of data ... ;
                navbarCtrl.selectByUrl($location.absUrl());
            });

            $scope.$watch('$location.absUrl()', function (locationPath) {
                navbarCtrl.selectByUrl(locationPath)
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

The directive's $watch calls a controller function, and that function has access to the controller $scope through its closure.

```
function NavbarCtrl($scope, $timeout, $http, $location, $attrs) {
    $scope.items = $scope.items || [];

    this.select = $scope.select = function (item) {
        angular.forEach($scope.items, function (item) {
            item.selected = false;
        });
        item.selected = true;
    };

    this.selectByUrl = function (url) {
        angular.forEach($scope.items, function (item) {
            if ('http://' + item.link === url) {
                $scope.select(item);
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Then, in my template, which I transclude, I have:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{active: item.selected}">
    <a href="/{{item.link}}">{{item.title}}</a>
</li>
```

In the page markup, I use it like this:

```
<div ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">
    <navbar heading="Navbar Heading"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah this is something I'm going to go for. I am always forgetting about directive to directive communication

Answer (score 1):

#### Custom repeater...

Building a custom repeater is a complicated task. Mostly because of performance issues but also because it should play well with other directives.

If you really need to build one, You must first dive into `ngRepeat` source code to understand some considerations and then to mutate it to your own needs.

ngRepeat now uses **$watchCollection** (*since 1.2*) which replaced the **deep $watch** hog.

---

#### Solution

So my recommendation is **do not build a custom repeater** , use `ngRepeat`!

I still don't know what you want to achieve but this is the construction.

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/pziqRzz0i1mU6eG5lAmd?p=preview

#### create another custom directive instead of `ngTransclude`

```
app.directive('myTransclude',function(){
  return {
    require: "^myColumnLayout",
    link: function(scope,elm,attr,ctrl,$transclude){
      $transclude(function(clone){
        elm.empty();
        elm.append(clone);
        ctrl.do("Hi")
      })
    }
  }
});
```

#### create your directive with ng-repeating **my-transclude** and a controller:

```
app.directive('myColumnLayout', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    transclude: true,
    controller: function(){
      this.do = function(x) {
        console.log(x)
      }
    },
    template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in collection track by $index" my-transclude></li></ul>',
    scope: {
      collection: '='
    }
  }
});
```

#### why?

- Now you have total control of the transclusion phase inside `my-transclude`
- you can define on the controller anything you need to share into the transcluded content.
- You are not getting your hands dirty with repeating stuff.

Comment: This is cool, thanks. Not exactly what I'm after but I will be using it somewhere else. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear for me what exactly you do but i fix some mistake in your directive as follows.

1. Clear the elem children before recreating them.
2. Note the third parameter of $watch function. It is necessary for watching a collection.

   ```
   app.directive('myColumnLayout', function () {
       return {
           restrict: 'EA',
           transclude: true,
           scope: {
               collection: '='
           },
           link: function (scope, elem, attrs, container, transclude) {
               scope.$watch('collection', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                   elem.empty();
                   for (var i = 0; i < newVal.length; i++) {
                       var li = angular.element('<li></li>');
                       var scp = scope.$parent.$new();
                       scp.item = newVal[i];
                       transclude(scp, function (clone) {
                           elem.append(clone);
                       });
                   }
               }, true);
           }
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: You can use `$watchCollection` for this.