# Am I have to use a pub/sub like service mechanizm for directives' comminucation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is my outer directive's template file:

```
<div class="outerDirective">
    <span>{{imgLoadStatus}}</span> 

    <imgDirective class="innerDirective">
        <img src="img/src.jpg"/>
    </imgDirective>

</div>
```

As you can see I have two nested directives. One is holding the image and the outer one is displays the load status. 
I need to update the `imgLoadStatus` $scope variable of outer directive.

I know I can manage this with a kind of Pub/Sub service but I'm curios that is there a build in Angular way for this kind of job? Or do you prefer a diffrent way?

Comment: just use `require`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672709/how-to-require-a-controller-in-an-angularjs-directive

Comment: @akonsu Ok that would work but I need more examples for fully understand this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21292184/149060 - the nested scope in that example is very like the nested directives you have here.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your inner-directive's definition, you'd want to define a "scope" property.

```
angular.module(...).directive(..., ...function () {

    var innerDirective = {
        templateUrl : ...,

        scope : {
            loadingState : "="
        },

        link : function (scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.update = function () {
                scope.loadingState.current += 1;
            };
        }
    };

    return innerDirective;
```

Inside of your outer-directive's template, when you call your inner-directive, you will add a "loading-state" attribute, and pass it a scope property from the outer-directive.
    // in your outer-directive:
    // $scope.loading.current = 0;
    // $scope.$watch("loading.current", function (newVal) { $scope.updateView(newVal); });

The `loadingState : "="` is a two-way data-binding between the inner scope and the outer scope.
The name you give it, inside of the inner-scope is the name of the property it expects in the HTML (almost like the HTML now has your constructor params).

There are cases where this will *not* go both ways, and will only go from parent to child.
Like if you try to make ngRepeat inner-directives.
Or if you use an ngIf to add/delete a child-directive.

I don't believe this is documented behaviour, but I do believe it's the *current* behaviour.

Comment: I'm "ngRepeating" the inner-directives. Thanx anyway.